# socket: server thread initial a new request to another server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

It's a client server mode. The server uses multi-thread to handle the client request, if a new client request to a particular server, the server will initialize a new thread to handle it. However, I need to add a logic flow to the server thread that it might also need to initialize a request to another server. Basically, the server itself behaves as a server and a client at the same time. It is useful for search, for example, if a client send a search request to a server, and the server doesn't find it in its local file, then it can request to another server to get the result and get back to the client.

I try to implement this by add a request method in the server thread run method, as:

```
// server thread handle request for client
public void run(){
  try{
    // input output stream with client
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clnt.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferReader in = new BufferReader( new InputStreamReader( clnt.getInputStream() ) );
    ...
    // try to initial a new request to anther server which is already listening
    reqstAntherServ();
    ...
  }
}
```

The reqstAntherServ method:

```
public void reqstAntherServ(){
  try{
    // initial a new socket request
    Socket reqstAnthrServ = new Socket(hostname, port);

    // input output stream with anther server
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clnt.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferReader in = new BufferReader( new InputStreamReader( clnt.getInputStream() ) );
    ...
  }
}
```

However, at running time I found that reqstAntherServ method seem does not initial a request successfully, I mean for example server A want to request Server B via the method, the result is that server B which is already listening does not hear any request. Normally, it should print out a message to the console indicating the socket has been created.

Then I thought it might be the thread thing, I guess a server thread can't both keep a communication with the client and initialize a new request at the same time. So I try to put the reqstAntherServ method into anther new thread. Basically, if the server wants to send a request to anther server, it needs to create a new thread which used to handle that. However, it doesn't work either.

I don't know what's the problem or is there another way to implement this mechanism? Thank you!

UPDATED! Include the initial a new thread to put the reqstAnerthServ method, what I tried is to use a static class as thread handler and put the content of reqstAnotherServ method into the run method, as:

```
private static class ThreadRqstAntherServ implements Runnable {
  ...
  public void run() {
    try{
    // initial a new socket request
    Socket reqstAnthrServ = new Socket(hostname, port);

    // input output stream with anther server
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clnt.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferReader in = new BufferReader( new InputStreamReader( clnt.getInputStream() ) );
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the server thread handler request for client, instead of call the reqstAntherServ method directly, I initial a new thread using the ThreadRqstAntherServ above, as:

```
// server thread handle request for client
public void run(){
  try{
    // input output stream with client
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clnt.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferReader in = new BufferReader( new InputStreamReader( clnt.getInputStream() ) );
    ...
    // try to initial a new request to anther server which is already listening
    Runnable r = new ThreadRqstAntherServ(...);
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    ...
  }
}
```

Also include the creating server process code, in the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  try{
    ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(port);
    while (true) {
      Socket clnt = serv.accept();
      Runnable rServ = new Threadhandler(clnt, ...); // thread handler for the server thread
      Thread tServ = new Thread(rServ);
      tServ.start();
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code that starts the new threads please?

Comment: Could you include the server code that accepts new connections and starts threads as well please?

Comment: @SimonC include it, sorry for the inconvenience, thank you!

Comment: Define 'does not initial a request successfully'. Your question is unintelligible at present.

Answer (score -2):

Problem solve, the reason is that since the server socket listens on two ports at the same time, so it needs to use extra thread to handler the second one, otherwise, the communication will be blocked.

Comment: Equally unintelligible. A ServerSocket does not listen at two ports.